# Shor: Modular exponentiation vs modular multiplication

Tags: shors-algorithm, quantum-phase-estimation, modular-exponentiation

In his original article [Polynomial-Time Algorithms for Prime Factorization
and Discrete Logarithms on a Quantum Computer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9508027.pdf), Peter Shor constructed an algorithm for finding a period $r$ of the modular exponentiation $a^x \mod N$, where $N$ is factored number, $a$ is random integer such that $1 < a < N$ and $\gcd\{a,N\} = 1$. This period $r$ is then used in factoring of integer $N = pq$ via the greatest common divisor: $p,q = \gcd\{a^{r/2} \pm 1, N\}$. The period $r$ is found with quantum phase estimation. This is a short description of Shor's factorization algorithm.

In the article [Circuit for Shor’s algorithm using 2n+3 qubits](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0205095.pdf), Stéphane Beauregard provides an implementation of Shor's algorithm which is almost the same as the one described above with the exception that rather than a period of the modular exponentiation, a period of the function $(ax) \mod N$ (modular multiplication) is searched for. This is firstly discussed on pg. 2 in fig. 1, and then several other times in the article.

**However, I failed to see how finding period of the modular exponentiation and the modular multiplication are equivalent problems. Could anyone shed more light on this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just an issue of terminology.

Given integers $a$ and $N$, you're looking for the [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) $r$ of $a$ mod $N$, that is, the smallest $r$ such that $a^r\equiv1\bmod N$. In this context, people use "period" and "order" interchangeably.

To find such $r$ via QPE, you want to look for a unitary $U$ which somehow encodes it in its eigenvalues — as QPE returns an approximation of an eigenvalue of $U$, when the input at the second register is the corresponding eigenstate. As it happens, if you use the unitary $U_{a,N}$ defined as $U_{a,N}|x\rangle=|ax\bmod N\rangle$, this will satisfy $U_{a,N}^r=I$, and thus its eigenvalues will be $\exp(2\pi i k/r)$ for $k=0,...,r-1$.

So I would say it's the "period" of the function $f:k\mapsto a^k\bmod N$, as the smallest $r$ such that $f(r)=f(0)=1$, and you retrieve it doing QPE on the unitary implementing the multiplication $x\mapsto ax\bmod N$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just one question: shouldn't be *for $k = 0...r-1$* at the end of second paragraph instead of *for $r = 0...r-1$*?

Comment: @MartinVesely of course, thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

Shor's algorithm finds the period of a modular multiplication by performing a modular exponentiation with a superposed exponent. The different authors are just emphasizing different parts of the algorithm; they're describing the same thing.